# Response::json() - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to `return Response::json('data', $request);` however, I am getting an error:

> FatalErrorException in ProjectsController.php line 74:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::json()

Where is the `Response::json()` is located? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use also the response() Helper. 


return response(['errorMsg' => [...]], 400); 


If your response is an Array then the helper will convert the array to json and set the right to header application/json.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

use the helper function in [laravel 5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses) instead:

```
return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);
```

This will create an instance of `\Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory`. See the phpDocs for possible parameters below:

```
/**
* Return a new JSON response from the application.
*
* @param string|array $data
* @param int $status
* @param array $headers
* @param int $options
* @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response 
* @static 
*/
public static function json($data = array(), $status = 200, $headers = array(), $options = 0){

    return \Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::json($data, $status, $headers, $options);
}
```

Comment: offtopic, how to get these data in view? Just using $name for 'Abigail' and $state for 'CA' ?

Comment: depends on your usage. a xhr request (ajax) would hold an object with `name` and `state` property @MASh

Comment: Can you explain a lil bit more? I am beginner.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can explain.. Maybe you should ask a new question and include details on what you want to achieve... @MASh

Comment: if I use view(someview)->with('name', "alex"); then in view I can get using {{ $name }}. Like this will I get 'CA'  using {{ $state }}?

Comment: Then what to write instead of {{ $state }}?

Answer (score 12):

You need to add **`use Response;`** facade in header at your file.

Only then you can successfully retrieve your data with

```
return Response::json($data);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 11):

After enough googling I found the answer from controller you need only a backslash like `return \Response::json(['success' => 'hi, atiq']);` . Or you can just return the array `return array('success' => 'hi, atiq');` which will be rendered as json  in Laravel version 5.2 .

Comment: Yes, You're a life saver, but why we didn't  use "use" statement.
You should have explained the why part as well!

Answer (score 4):

However, the previous answer could still be confusing for some programmers. Most especially beginners who are most probably using an older book or tutorial.
Or perhaps you still feel the facade is needed. Sure you can use it.
Me for one I still love to use the facade, this is because some times while building my api I forget to use the '\' before the Response.

if you are like me,
simply add

```
   "use Response;"
```

above your class ...extends contoller.
this should do.

with this you can now use:

```
$response = Response::json($posts, 200);
```

instead of:

```
$response = \Response::json($posts, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

From a controller you can also return an Object/Array and it will be sent as a JSON response (including the correct HTTP headers).

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Customer::find($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

although `Response::json()` is not getting popular of recent, that does not stop you and Me from using it.
In fact you don't need any facade to use it,

instead of:

```
$response = Response::json($messages, 200);
```

Use this:

```
$response = \Response::json($messages, 200);
```

with the slash, you are sure good to go.

Comment: you mean you don't need an "alias" to use it? because that is the Facade you are referencing