# Can't Access JSON response in AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to access JSON object from my controller in my AJAX success syntax, but it doesn't seem to work. All im getting is *undefine* if i do

> response.success

this is what the console spits out of *response* (console.log(response))

> {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,
>   setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} abort: ƒ ( statusText )
>   always: ƒ () catch: ƒ ( fn ) done: ƒ () fail: ƒ ()
>   getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ () getResponseHeader: ƒ ( key )
>   overrideMimeType: ƒ ( type ) pipe: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress
>   */ ) progress: ƒ () promise: ƒ ( obj ) readyState: 4 responseText: " ↵     .container{ ↵           width: 800px; ↵         margi" setRequestHeader:
>   ƒ ( name, value ) state: ƒ () status: 200 statusCode: ƒ ( map )
>   statusText: "OK" then: ƒ ( onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress )
>   **proto**: Object

AJAX code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#unggah-pembuktian').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });
      jQuery.ajax({
       url: "{{ url('/unggah') }}",
       method: 'get',
       data: {
        kodePembayaran: jQuery('#kode-pembayaran').val(),
        bukti_pembayaran: jQuery('#customFile').val()
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){     
          console.log(response.success);  
        },
      error: function(response){
        console.log(response.success);
        console.log(response);
      }
      });
   });
});
```

Function in controller

```
public function unggahBuktiPembayaran(Request $request) {
        $status = $this->cekKodePembayaran($request);

        if ($status == TRUE) {

        $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
            'bukti_pembayaran' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:20480'
            ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                "success" => "F"
           ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                "success" => "T"            
            ]);
        }
```

Any ideas why? Sorry if this post is messy or is incorrect in anyway, im still getting used to stackoverflow.

Comment: I think your AJAX call is actually going error function, I suggest renaming it to error instead of response and a breakpoint in chrome see where it is actually hitting when the response comes success or error function. If this case is true most likely your API is not handling the negative use case when you API fails, as I can't tell as the API code not so detailed answer.

Comment: What does console.log(response); gives you? Maybe you're not getting enough informations with response.success

Comment: to me it looks like your server isn't sending plain json back, but a css/html header (_"responseText: " ↵ .container{ ↵ width: 800px; ↵ margi"_) -> jquery can't interpret that as json. Look into network tab what you acutally get returned, if it's not pure json, fix it on the server!

Comment: @SaktiChourasia yes, it is going to the error function. I'm new to AJAX so im not really sure why that happens. But the main focus of my problem is that "response" doesnt contain the value that i wanted

Comment: @harisdev i paste the console.log(response) above

Comment: @Jeff yeah i notice that too, do you know why? Why doesn't response contain what i assign on my function?

Comment: That's a problem/question for lavarel-users, which I'm not, sadly. But try a search for something like "laravel json response"

Comment: I don't see any issue in the frontend, I think the problem is in the server side. Hit the API via Postman or something and see if you are getting the proper response.

Comment: this answers might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975028/4830296; https://stackoverflow.com/a/39224992/4830296 - they bascally say you need to add `use Response;` to your controller script _or_ access the class via root namespace: `return \Response()->json...`

Comment: @Jeff i have look to those links you gave before i even made this post, and that doesn't seem to fix my problem. I'm trying to look in the console network tab now, where do i look to see what gets returned?