# response()->json unable to decode in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

We are using Laravel version 5.*
We do not want to change this code in our project 
response()->json

It will reflect the whole application and It is terrible. So we need a proper solution and I have found the solution in the comments of this questions. 
Thanks.

Here is scenario:

```
$response = response()->json(['code' => 1,
    'message' => 'Content-type is ABC',
    'data' => ['code'=>1,'message'=>'Content-type is ABC']
]);

echo json_decode($response); // It always print null and nothing. 
dd($response);  // print Null
return $response; //You will get proper json response in function return.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nocac.png)

Comment: so, what is your question again ?

Comment: Try return `json_encode(['code' => 1,
                        'message' => 'Content-type is ABC',
                        'data' => ['code'=>1,'message'=>'Content-type is ABC']
                    ]);`

Comment: As far  as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31865557/4964822) goes, you should be able to print it.

Comment: We would need to see more code to debug this.

Comment: Your response is null that's why

Comment: `dd($response->getContent());` will print the json response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response::json() - Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865493/responsejson-laravel-5-1)

Comment: @Rockcat has nothing at all to do with that question ...

Comment: `dd($repsonse)` prints null? That's strange it should print an instance of a [`JsonResponse`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php)

Comment: dd(json_decode($response->getContent()));  // It will return decoded json

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$response =  response()->json(['code' => 1,
                    'message' => 'Content-type is ABC',
                    'data' => ['code'=>1,'message'=>'Content-type is ABC']
                ]);
$x = $response->getContent();
return $x;
OR
return $response;
```

output will be

```
  "{"code":1,"message":"Content-type is ABC","data":{"code":1,"message":"Content-type is ABC"}}"
```

Comment: OP does get the response properly as he mentions in his last line `return $response; //You will get proper json response in function return.`

Comment: both will give proper json response

Comment: OP does get a response, but he is wondering why `dd($response);` prints null.

Comment: No..`dd($response)` is showing a json object.But `json_decode($response)` showing null.

Comment: It is written `dd($response);  // print Null` but `return $response; //You will get proper json response in function return.` in the post.

Comment: @vivek_23 the OP's code is clearly trying to `json_decode` the Response Object, not the JSON contained in it

Comment: @lagbox You didn't get me. His code has `dd($response);` which he wants to see what's inside `$response`. He does get json as response in his API.

Comment: `response()->json()` will create a json object..When you `dd()` it will show the object.When you return it,only the actual data will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

try getContent():

```
echo $response->getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $response =  response()->json(['code' => 1,
                    'message' => 'Content-type is ABC',
                    'data' => ['code'=>1,'message'=>'Content-type is ABC']
                ]);
```

You can Direct Print

`echo $response->getContent()`