# What is the equivalent of codeigniter row_array in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I got ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ route('master.cabang_get') }}",
    data : {id: id},
    success: function (result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result['"kode_cabang"'])
        $('#id').val(result.id);
        $('#kode_cabang').val(result.kode_cabang);
        $('#nama_cabang').val(result.nama_cabang);

        $("#myModal").find('.modal-title').text('Edit Cabang');
        $("#myModal").modal('show',{backdrop: 'true'});           
    }
});
```

and this is the controller

```
$data = DB::table('master_cabang')->where('id', $id)->first();
    echo json_encode($data);
```

in codeigniter,i can use ->row_array(); and return the data as json_encode. so i can console.log(result['') in the javascript. but when i use laravel. it's undefined. but the response looks like this

```
{"id":10,"kode_cabang":"BDG910","nama_cabang":"Bandung","createdat":"2020-04-12 06:17:18","updatedat":null}
```

basically. how to return single row as an array in laravel ? or how to extract the result response in javascript ?

Comment: You can inprove add ***dataType: 'json'*** in your Ajax block or use ***JSON.parse(result)*** in your success function

Comment: ahhh, yeah it's solved the problem. i need to add dataType: json. thankssss

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865493/responsejson-laravel-5-1  
`return response()->json($data);`

Comment: Laravel cast result to json, whether it is array or object, create a model and do:  return MasterCabang::find($id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your response is an `array`, a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections), a `Model` or an object that inherits one of the following:

- `SymfonyResponse`
- `Arrayable`
- `Jsonable`
- `ArrayObject`
- `JsonSerializable`

Laravel will automatically convert the response to `JSON`. ([Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#creating-responses))

In short, to return your query result as JSON you can simply cast it to an array and return it from your route/controller method e.g.:

```
public function yourControllerMethod()
{
    return (array)DB::table('master_cabang')->where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

Comment: i use " return json_encode($data); " in the controller. then in the javascript, result['id'] is still undefined. but result showing the same as in the question

Comment: @Ghozizzz Are you getting any errors in the console/network tab? Also, I had made a mistake in my answer and have since updated it.