# Laravel 4 return json as response

Tags: json, laravel, httpresponse

I work on old system - laravel 4.1/4.2 - my controler returns number in response:

```
return 4;
```

but browser shows `Content-Type: text/html` (not json) and debugbar add also some html to that response.

When I try this from laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses):

```
return Response::json(['result' => 4 ]);
```

I get error (I to of php controler file I have `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;` )

> Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::json()

I also try to use

```
$response = new Response(200, array(), ['result' => 4]);
return $response->json();
```

but I get

> The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.

How to get json in response (without debugbar stuff)?

---

Update: (I test proposition from Tim Levis comment)

When I try (with and without `use Response`)

```
return response()->json(['result' => 4], 200);
```

I get

> Call to undefined function App\Controllers\Api\response()

---

Update2: Someone suggest that there is already answer for Laravel 5 - which actually works in L4 - but this is accidentally I think - usually L5 solutions NOT works on L4 so we should not mix this two framework versions

Comment: I don't know if this syntax is valid in Laravel 4, but it's typically done as `return response()->json(['result' => 4], 200);` in more recent versions. It seems odd that `Response::json()` wouldn't work, unless your use statement is wrong. I think it would be `use Response;` (the Facade), not `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response::json() - Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865493/responsejson-laravel-5-1)

Comment: @TimLewis the `use Response;` with  `Response::json(["result"=>4]);` works - please write your comment as answer - I will accept it

Comment: Re: update2; Laravel is generally quite good at being backwards compatible. One of the answers on the the Laravel 5 solution question using `Response::json()` works because that's the Laravel 4 syntax, which was preserved in Laravel 5 and onwards. The actual solution of `response()->json()` will not work, as those were introduced in Laravel 5 :) And you confirmed that by the `Call to undefined function App\Controllers\Api\response()` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Response::json()` should work in Laravel 4.2, as versions prior to 5 used Facades (`Response::`) instead of global methods (`response()`).

The main issue here is the imported `Response` class is not the Facade, but rather a Symphony component. To fix this issue, use the correct import:

```
use Response; // Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response (or Laravel 4.2 equivalent)

class ExampleController extends Controller {
  public function exampleRequest(){
    return Response::json(['result' => 4], 200);
  }
}
```

Sidenote; `return ['result' => 4];` "works", as Laravel guesses content type for return statements in Controllers, but it's better to be specific to avoid any issues.

---

Update: you can use shortcut which works without `use Response` statement

```
return \Response::json(4);`
```

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Appreciate the shortcut edit, just note that `json(4)` and `json(['result' => 4])` likely aren't the same when trying to access response :)

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally I discovered that when I return array

```
return ['result' => 4 ];
```

then response have `Content-Type: application/json` and not have debugbar stuff - I have no idea why - but it works :)